# Why doesn't my method return char*

Tags: c, char, return-value

I'm trying to compile the following:

```c
void chen() {
     char s[50];
     char s1[30], s2[30]; int t;
     printf("Nhap chuoi 1: ");
     gets(s1);
     s = insert(s1);  // Error here
     printf("chen chuoi 2 vao chuoi 1: ");
     puts(s);
}

char* insert(char* s1) {
    return s1;
}

int main() {
    chen();
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is telling me:

> Errors: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[50]' from type

Can someone tell me why the compiler thinks `insert` returns an `int`? What do I need to do to fix the code above?

Comment: (The button with `{}` is the button to format the text as code.)

Comment: Select the code and press `{}` button on the toolbar to for,at your code.

Comment: And please clean up your code before posting, all those comments are completely irrelevant and distracting.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't declared the `insert()` function before you used it, so the compiler assumes it returns `int`. Put this before your `chen()` function:

```
char *insert(char *s1);
```

Comment: Even then, he can't assign a pointer to an array.

Comment: @DanielFischer: true, but I thought I'd explain the immediate problem so user1155771 then has the joy of thinking through the next problem for themselves :-)